# Deny movement in pygame when player would collide with a wall

Tags: python, pygame

I've been having trouble with collisions in pygame. Specifically, I have a player and a list of walls, and if they collide, I'm supposed to prevent any more movement in that direction.

I've tried many guides but I can't seem to get this to work myself.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

playerX = 380 #Player X coordinate
playerY = 380 #Player Y coordinate
playerXVel = 10 #Horizontal Velocity
playerYVel = 10 #Vertical Velocity
overworld = (248, 192, 117)

run = True

while run: #The game starts running
    win.fill(overworld)
    pygame.time.delay(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #You can stop the game now too
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    class Player: #This is you
        def __init__(self):
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(playerX,playerY,50,50)
    player = Player()

    class Wall: #The walls
        def __init__(self, pos):
            walls.append(self)
            self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 50, 50)
    walls = []
    
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #To retain the feel of retro video games, I have made it impossible to walk diagonally
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerY -= playerYVel
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_s]:
        playerX -= playerXVel
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
        playerY += playerYVel
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and not keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_w]:
        playerX += playerXVel

    #I copied this section of code
    #Credit: https://www.pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html
    level = [
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "W              W",
        "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ]
    x = y = 0
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "W":
                Wall((x, y)) 
            x += 50
        y += 50
        x = 0

    #Drawing every rectangle in :3
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), player.rect)
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (143, 41, 3), wall.rect)

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

So far so good. I have walls, I have a player, and that player can move. The player can, however, walk through the walls.

I want to put a piece of code in that prevents velocity being added or removed if the player collides with a wall. This what I've tried for walking upwards, but it just makes it so that I cannot walk upwards altogether

```
        for allwalls in walls:
            if not player.rect.colliderect(allwalls):
                playerY -= playerYVel
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/what I should be entering into the code instead to prevent a player from moving through a wall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the objects once before the application loop. You don't need the variables `playerX` and `playerY` at all. Use `player.rect.x` and `player.rect.y` instead.

Store the position of the player before moving it. If a collision is detected, restore player position:

```py
oldPlyerX, oldPlyerY = player.rect.topleft          # store player position

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
    player.rect.y -= playerYVel
if keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_s]:
    player.rect.x -= playerXVel
if keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
    player.rect.y += playerYVel
if keys[pygame.K_d] and not keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_w]:
    player.rect.x += playerXVel

for allwalls in walls:
    if player.rect.colliderect(allwalls):
        player.rect.topleft = oldPlyerX, oldPlyerY # restore player position
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

playerXVel = 10 #Horizontal Velocity
playerYVel = 10 #Vertical Velocity
overworld = (248, 192, 117)

class Player: #This is you
    def __init__(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(380,380,50,50)
player = Player()

class Wall: #The walls
    def __init__(self, pos):
        walls.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 50, 50)
walls = []

#I copied this section of code
#Credit: https://www.pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html
level = [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "W              W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
]
x = y = 0
for row in level:
    for col in row:
        if col == "W":
            Wall((x, y)) 
        x += 50
    y += 50
    x = 0

run = True

while run: #The game starts running
    win.fill(overworld)
    pygame.time.delay(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get(): #You can stop the game now too
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    oldPlyerX, oldPlyerY = player.rect.topleft
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()  #To retain the feel of retro video games, I have made it impossible to walk diagonally
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.rect.y -= playerYVel
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_w] and not keys[pygame.K_s]:
        player.rect.x -= playerXVel
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_a] and not keys[pygame.K_d]:
        player.rect.y += playerYVel
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and not keys[pygame.K_s] and not keys[pygame.K_w]:
        player.rect.x += playerXVel

    for allwalls in walls:
        if player.rect.colliderect(allwalls):
            player.rect.topleft = oldPlyerX, oldPlyerY

    #Drawing every rectangle in :3
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), player.rect)
    for wall in walls:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (143, 41, 3), wall.rect)

    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```